# The relationship of subnormal subgroups and modular subgroups of a finite group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called subnormal if it's a term of a composition series of $G$, and is called modular if it's a modular element of the subgroup lattice $L(G)$. My question is that, must every subnormal subgroup of $G$ be modular, and must every modular subgroup of $G$ be subnormal?

Comment: In [this example](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Derived_subgroup_centralizes_normal_subgroup_whose_automorphism_group_is_abelian) it is said that the subgroup lattice of $D_4$ is not modular. Recall that $D_4$ is nilpotent, hence every subgroup is subnormal. This means that subnormal does not imply modular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the comment, I've proved that neither of subnormality no modularity implied the other. As Crostul noted in the comment, $D_4$ contains subnormal subgroups that are not modular. An the other hand, $L(S_3)$ is a modular lattice, while second order subgroups of $S_3$ are not subnormal.